# Showing that two elements in a set are equal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Consider the list of elements $e, a , a^2, a^3, b, ab, a^2b, a^3b$
>
> If two of these are equal, then cancelling gives $a^r=b^s$ for some $r \in \{0,1,2,3\}, s\in\{0,1\}$

I am unsure about what the book's solution means by cancelling and how this result would show the list is not made up of distinct elements. But I am then told that since this is not the case, the 8 listed elements are distinct. Could someone break this down and explain?

Earlier in the question, I proved that $a^4=b^2=e$ if that helps.

I don't think a definition of the group is needed, but I will make changes to the description if there are insufficient details to answer the question.

Comment: It actually said _Consider the **list** of elements_, not a set.

Comment: Can we only say that a list of elements form a set if all the elements are distinct?

Comment: I think so if the list is un-ordered.

Comment: You can consider the set $\{0,1,0,4\}$, but it is **equal** to the set $\{0,1,4\}$ and some would consider the former improperly written.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Cancelling** is multiplying both sides of an equality of the kind $$ab=c$$
by $b^{-1}$ on the right, or by $a^{-1}$ on the left, to get $$\text{either} \qquad a=cb^{-1}\qquad \text{or}  \qquad b=a^{-1}c$$
In your case, you would get from $$a^nb^m=a^pb^q$$ to $$a^{n-p}=b^{q-m}.$$

---

Now for the second part of your question, it looks like your book is aiming at a contradiction by arguing that $k=4$ and $\ell=2$ are the smallest positive powers that allow for the equality $a^k=b^\ell$ to hold. But without more information it is impossible to tell why this should be the case here.

Note however that the sentence

> If two of these are equal, then cancelling gives $a^r=b^s$ for some $r \in \{0,1,2,3\}, s\in\{0,1\}$

should specify $r$ and $s$ not both $0$. Otherwise the statement is empty.

Comment: I think my main confusion lies in cancelling what exactly? Do I put every two elements in the list equal to each other and try to cancel or is it to do with the statement $a^4=b^2=e$. The fact that the book does not elaborate much makes me think it's a simple point I'm missing.

Comment: Cancelling whatever needs to be cancelled to get from, e.g. $ab=a^2b$, to $e=a$. The book says that if any two elements from the list are equal, then you can apply right and left cancellations to turn that equality into one of the kind $a^r=b^s$ for some $r$, $s$ that are small and not both $0$.

Comment: I'm starting to think I misunderstood what the book said. Is it saying that If we ASSUME that two elements from the list are equal, we end up with
$a^r=b^s$ for some $r\in\{0,1,2,3\},s\in\{0,1\}$, which is NOT true. Therefore, the elements are all distinct.

Comment: Pressed enter before I finished typing!

Comment: @s.xw that's what I wrote in the 2nd part of the answer, *your book is aiming at a contradiction by arguing that $k=4$ and $\ell=2$ are the smallest positive powers that allow for the equality $a^k=b^\ell$ to hold.* Using this it proves that all elements in the list are distinct. Nothing's wrong.

Comment: Reading your answer again, it completely makes sense now. Thank you.

Comment: @s.xw Great! You're welcome.